# PIC Kit 3 - PIC32 memory mismatch error

Tags: pic, microchip, pickit

after I worked for a while with the PIC16 microcontrollers, I wanted to get known to PIC32 microcontrollers.

But I have a problem.
If I try to run a simple program on the PIC32MX110F016B or on the PIC32MX220F032B I get always the same error message:

> Failed to program device
>    Selected device and target: memory    mismatch.

I use the PIC Kit 3 combined with MPLAB to program the PICs and with the PIC16s it worked always pretty well.
The PIC is powered from the PIC Kit 3(3.25V) and I connected it this way:

(PC3 = PIC Kit 3 pin, MC = Microcontroller pin)

> - PC3 MCLR -> MC MCRL
> - PC3 VDD -> MC VDD
> - PC3 VSS -> MC VSS
> - PC3 PGD -> MC PGED1
> - PC3 PGC -> MC PGEC1

I also connected a 10K resistor from MCLR to the VDD pin.

And I think the only important config I set in the program is right, too:

```
#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx1        // ICE/ICD Comm Channel Select (Communicate on PGEC1/PGED1)
```

Here the full console output:

> Connecting to MPLAB PICkit 3...
>
> Currently loaded firmware on PICkit 3
>   Firmware Suite
>   Version.....01.36.10 
>  Firmware type..............PIC32MX
>
> Programmer to target power is enabled - VDD = 3,250000 volts. 
>   Target device PIC32MX110F016B found.
>  Device ID Revision = A1
>
> The following memory area(s) will be programmed: 
>  program memory:
>   start
>  address = 0x0, end address = 0xfff
>  boot config
>   memory
>  configuration memory
>
> Device Erased...
>
> Programming... 
>  Failed to program device 
>  Selected device and
>   target: memory mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PIC32s have a vcore/vcap pin that needs to have a sufficiently large, low esr capacitor connected otherwise you will get strange errors like this and it would not run stable. In the datasheet, there's a section detailing minimum connections including the minimum capacitor value.